# update multiple rows with single update SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why does this SQL query not work :

```
update MyTable
set IsOk = 1
where MyName = 'OK'
```

error is :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Can you check 'OK' value might be containing dirty value? If not, 1 value might be also.